# shiny-server script resulting in 'Error in Calendar: could not find function "Calendar"'

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

R version:  4.1.0
Shiny Server v1.5.16.958
Node.js v12.20.0

I have a shiny-server script that I'm having issues with. When I call this script using a web browser, I immediately get: "Disconnected from the server. Reload". Upon inspecting the browser debug console, I received this debug information that I'm not quite sure what to do about. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can resolve this? :

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:46259
gdata: read.xls support for 'XLS' (Excel 97-2004) files ENABLED.

gdata: read.xls support for 'XLSX' (Excel 2007+) files ENABLED.

Attaching package: ‘gdata’

The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

    nobs

The following object is masked from ‘package:utils’:

    object.size

The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:

    startsWith


Attaching package: ‘bizdays’

The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

    offset

Warning: Error in Calendar: could not find function "Calendar"
  [No stack trace available]
Error in Calendar(hdays, weekdays = c("saturday", "sunday")) : 
  could not find function "Calendar"

shiny-server-client.min.js:1 The application unexpectedly exited.
```

Comment: Which package contains the Calendar function? is it installed and loaded by `library(package)` on the server?

Comment: I believe it's the bizdays package.

Comment: Yes it is installed. It's on version 1.0.8.

Comment: Is it installed for root? if you login as a super user with sudo su, and then type R, then `library(bizdays)` does it work or say something like cannot find package?

Answer (score 0):

We have figured out the problem. Bizdays has deprecated the function 'Calendar'. In our Server.R file we had to update the code to use 'create.calender' instead.